# Coloured log output is not reflecting in log4j 2 after providing in xml

Tags: log4j2

i have configured the below xml to get the coloured output in console, but still not getting the coloured o/p

```
  <PatternLayout  pattern="%highlight{%d %-5p [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n}{FATAL=red,ERROR=red, WARN=yellow bold, INFO=red, DEBUG=green bold, TRACE=blue}"/>
```